# React-native-slider: not able to set Thumb height to more than 40 (Android)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Ive noticed I am not able to set the thumb height to more than 40 on Android (see screenshot attached). Somehow there is a max height of 40 set somewhere. Any idea how to fix?

[image]

```
<Slider
              trackStyle={customStyles7.track}
              thumbStyle={customStyles7.thumb}
              value={this.state.value}
              onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({value})} />

var customStyles7 = StyleSheet.create({
  track: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
  },
  thumb: {
    width: 58,
    height: 58,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderRadius: 30,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone having a similar issue as I have, the slider default height has been set to 40 in the slider.js.

Look for the following in slider.js and change it to what you need

```
var defaultStyles = ...
```